# Is it possible to fill the ballon or a bottle with vacuum?

Tags: vacuum

Is it possible to fill the ballon or a bottle with vacuum? If so how do they do it? With a vacuum machine that sucks all the air inside the substance?

Comment: "Fill" isn't really the right word. You create a vacuum inside a container by pumping the air _out._ As for a balloon, you can search this site for questions about "vacuum balloon." TLDR: Any container that is strong enough to not be crushed by atmospheric pressure when the air inside is removed would be too thick and clunky to be called a "balloon." (also, too heavy to float, if that's what you're after.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your question is worded, it's like you mean "filling a balloon with vacuum" or with "nothing". If so, then that is meaningless, since by definition, "nothing" cannot occupy a space. However, I suspect this is not what you mean.

If you mean *using* a vacuum to inflate a balloon, then initially the balloon must have some gas. The chamber containing the balloon is evacuated which decreases the pressure in the chamber, thus increasing the pressure in balloon causing it to expand.

> With a vacuum machine that sucks all the air inside the substance?

But something tells me you might be referring to *vacuum sealing*, the process of packing a product where air is removed from the package just before sealing it. One way to do this is to already have the container and contents inside it, placed in a vacuum chamber and sealed. Since they were sealed at low pressure, there is no need to remove air anymore. When you open the package you'll hear a hissing sound as air rushes back into the container.

Find more information on how vacuum sealing is done, click [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_packing).

Comment: Re, "...package and contents placed in a vacuum chamber and sealed..." That would work, but it's not generally how they do it. There are cheaper ways. For example, you can use a countertop appliance to vacuum seal things in plastic bags; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-_AZ23DwcGA (watch from 2:05 to 2:35). To vacuum seal cooked foods in glass jars, Google for instructions for "home canning."

Comment: @SolomonSlow Ahah. But it is one way to do it. Especially when dealing with drinks, sauces and “wet” foods. Thanks for the info. I’ll edit my answer and I’ll watch the video sometime today. Cheers.